# DI code generator generated code uses non-existing function `ensureFunction`

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I tried [di Code Generator](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial/blob/master/Chapter_07/bin/generator.dart) from the AngularDart tutorial but the generated code contains a lot of lines like:

```dart
"incrementHours()": (scope) => ensureFunction(_incrementHours(scope), "incrementHours")(),
```

but the function `ensureFunction()` is unknown.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not di generator, but angular static parser generator that generates those lines. Please make sure that you have the following imports in the parser [header file](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/master/lib/tools/expression_extractor.dart#L36).

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import "package:angular/core/parser/utils.dart";
```

Comment: Thanks your for the info. I used the files from the angular.dart.tutorial which seems to not have this core/parser/utils import either. https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial/blob/master/Chapter_07/lib/parser_gen_header.dart

Comment: The tutorial might be a bit broken at the moment. Track here https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial/issues/35

Comment: Thanks! Got it working. Using static injector seems to provide huge performance improvement.